# I'm trying solve a problem using different versions of SAT, how exactly does mixing SAT affect the hardness of the problem?

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes, 3-sat, 2-sat

I'm trying to solve a problem which I can solve in 3SAT or as a mixed 2,3,4 SAT. I know how hard each of those categories are individually and know the derivations of their hardness individually. But I don't see how those can be combined to give me an idea of comparative hardness of 3SAT vs 2,3,4 SAT. By how hard, I mean what's the scaling with increasing numbers of variables.

Comment: As soon as you allow an arbitrary number of clauses with $3$ or more literals the problem becomes $\mathsf{NP}$-hard. For any fixed number of clauses with $3$ or more variables the problem is still in $\mathsf{P}$. In fact, the problem is in $\mathsf{P}$ even if the above clauses are at most $c \log n$ for some constant $c$, where $n$ is the number of variables.

Answer (score 1):

I think Steven's comment answers this sufficiently: 2SAT is in P, anything above that is NP-hard. By mixing it I just have two different NP-hard problems. How exactly 3SAT and 2,3,4 SAT differ in scaling probably depends on my algorithm.